# Foregroundservice startforeground doesn't show notification

Tags: android, service, android-service, android-notifications, foreground-service

I have a channel defined, and notification defined that I send to startforeground with notification Id different from 0.
I also searched in google lot, but I can't find- why startforeground doesn't show the notification??????

Please help!
It's really frustrating me!!!!!

Comment: Are you also calling "notificationManager.notify();" ?
Here is a good read for Oreo https://androidclarified.com/creating-notification-channels-on-android-oreo-with-example/

Comment: If it's possible, could you provide a code of your ForegroundService and Notification?

Comment: Notification is like the android developers' guide and in the foregroundservice in onStartCommand I create the notification and then startforeground with Id 1 and the notification. (I created the channel in the first launch of the app).

Comment: @JakeB I try the service and in android 7 it worked but in android 9 it doesn't show notification and the service shut down after minute and half. When I did "notify" it just showed notification but still shut down after minute and half

Comment: Provide sample, or it's totally unclear question

Answer (score 0):

I just solved it.
I tried the app on other real device and it worked, so in my phone (when I tried the first time) I deleted the app and clear its data and then ran the app again and its worked.